# plotting very large 2D color map / waterfall / spectrogram

Tags: matplotlib, spectrogram

I am using matplotlib's `pcolormesh` for 2D plotting of large sets of X Y Z data where Z is the color intensity.

I get the plots I want, but as the data is getting larger, the plotting gets slower and slower (> 30 min for each plot).

Is there any way to go about this limitation?

Comment: Maybe you can consider plotting a smaller dataset. Usually it does not make sense to plot more points than the resolution of your screen or printer would allow for anyways.

Comment: My problem is that in my data set some global structures in the spectrum is visible only in large plots. The best would be to plot everything in a single plot, since it would cause a single scaling for everything. Plotting into different pictures would cause slightly different color scaling.

Comment: Sure. But how large is "large"? If the aim is e.g. to show a plot on a usual HD screen, you would need a maximum of roughly 2000 x 1000 =2 Million pixels. Plotting a pcolormesh with 2 Million pixels takes much less than a second. So something with your code is wrong or you're plotting too many (unneeded, because not displayable) pixels.

Comment: Currently 7681 x 10000 which is nearly 8 million points. and that is just half an hour of data. The data set is several hours long. :-(

Comment: That's my point: You do not want to plot every single point if at the end several points are mapped to the same pixel on screen. Rather use a corser grid and average the data to it before plotting.